# Postman big number issue

Tags: javascript, postman

I need to store the EventTypeId below in a global variable in Postman to be used on later tests:

```
{
    "EventTypeId": 8565382127936807869,
    "ValueName": "Engine Load Calculated",
    "FormatType": "Value",
    "DisplayUnits": "%",
    "EventType": "Custom",
    "Description": "Test Roja"
}
```

Because of the JS limit the value is stored as 8565382127936808000 and it fails when compared to the original one.

Is there a way to preserve it?

Comment: Make it a string

Comment: Thanks Wendelin. Please can you show me a little code on how to do it in Postman? I'll be glad of it.

Answer (score 1):

```
str =  pm.response.text().replace(/[:|: *](\d+)/g,'"$1"');

console.info(str)

console.log(JSON.parse(str).EventTypeId)

pm.globals.set("value",JSON.parse(str).EventTypeId)
```

**Here we are enclosing that number in double quotes and then parsing to json so that you get the correct value as string**

Comment: Might need to adjust this snippets here to provide a way to save to a Global variable anf then a potential way to use the value is subsequent requests 

Comment: @DannyDainton I think OPS is aware of that main concern was about the rounding anyways added that for future readers :D

Answer (score 0):

You could save the value as a string:

```
pm.globals.set('event_id', String(pm.response.json().EventTypeId))
```

When you need to use that in a script:

```
let eventTypeId = parseInt(pm.globals.get('event_id')
```

Comment: hi danny it will round it to the valid number before converting it to string

Comment: its a 2^63 and max length in JS is 2^53

Comment: Fair point, didn't even try it 

Comment: :D ya i wracked my head a lot too its an interesting issue , it would be great to have a native solution in postman itself

Comment: It's not really a 'Postman' issue but handling it in a way that you don't have to jump through hoops would be better.

Comment: Yes its a node js issue but if there is a command for users that can be used to print big decimal  , ( "likehow postman response is retrieved correctly") it would be really great